# Azure function or similar to list Recovery Points

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a lot of vms with backup enabled and I need to list every recovery point available from every configured backup.

Currently I am doing rest api calls but I keep hitting the api read limit, and it's only getting worse.

I figured there must be a way to consolidate this information in a function and only call it once, but it doesn't seem to have a binding for backup vaults.

How can I go about achieving this? I need a way to get every single recovery point available, from each backup vault.

Comment: Did you try to use Azure Event Grid, to listen to Azure Backup events?

Maybe receive an event every time a back is made and store it in a Table Storage, or something similar.

Comment: I looked into it. Event grid system topics doesn't have a "Topic Type" for recovery services.